# How to get IPv6 from LPRT ftp command

Tags: java, ftp

I am creating a FTP sever . According to FTP specifications they have added new command called LPRT .

Its format is LPRT 6,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,193,160

Now i am able to get FTP port from it using logic below.But I need IPV6 address as well from this string .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(
            "6,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,193,160");

      final String portStr = st.nextToken(); 
      final int lastDelimIdx =portStr.lastIndexOf(',', portStr.lastIndexOf(',') - 1);
      final StringTokenizer portst = new StringTokenizer(portStr.substring(lastDelimIdx + 1, portStr.length()), ",");
      final int p1 = Integer.parseInt(portst.nextToken());
      final int p2 = Integer.parseInt(portst.nextToken());
      final int dataPort = (p1 << 8) | p2;
      System.out.println(dataPort);
}
```

Can some one help me to find the IPv6 address from this string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LPRT and LPSV  are considered obsolete, see https://www.iana.org/assignments/ftp-commands-extensions/ftp-commands-extensions.txt. To use IPv6 use EPSV and EPRT which are specified in [RFC2428](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2428).

If you still need to know how do deal with LPRT look into the obsolete [RFC1639](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1639). For example:

```
LPRT 6,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,193,160
```

means that the 16 numbers after the host length argument are the bytes of the address and then follows the port address length with 2 bytes, i.e.

```
[0000:0000:0000:0000:0300:0000:0000:0000]:49568
```

Comment: yes you are right , But our implementation says if EPRT fails then use LPRT hence we have to use it

Comment: I checked this link but unfortunately i did not find how they are representing IPv6 in format

Comment: @ShowStopper: I think it's quite clear, but see example in edited question.

Answer (score 0):

I created a program which does this extraction

```
    public static String longToIP(long[] ip) {
    String ipString = "";

    int flag = 0;
    for (long crtLong : ip) {

        if (flag == 2) {
            ipString = ipString + ":";
            flag = 0;
        }
        String s = Long.toHexString(crtLong & 0xFFFFFFFFL);
        if (s.length() == 1) {
            s = "0" + s;
        }
        ipString = ipString + "" + s;
        flag++;

    }
    return ipString;

}
```

Input = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 }

OutPut = {0000:0000:0000:0000:0300:0000:0000:0000}